# Why I am getting uncaught exception: out of memory while running Angular spec file using Jasmine and Karma

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, karma-runner

Whenever I tried to run Karma test runner with jasmine framework using command (npm run test:firefox ).I am getting the following error even I have spec files written.

**[image: 0 specs, 0 failures, randomized with seed 83975Error during loading: uncaught exception: out of memory]**

I have Node js version - v12.4.0 and NPM version - 6.9.0 ,Angular 7 and 16 GB RAM running on Windows 7.

Comment: Do you only get this on firefox or on all browsers?

Comment: in other browsers too  like chrome browser

Comment: How many tests do you have all together?

Comment: i have only 10 spec files

Comment: We might need to see an example of one of your tests. One of them may be doing something very strange.